# How to build neo4j-jdbc driver from official repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, neo4j

I wanted to use the neo4j-jdbc (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc) to connect to my Neo4j 3.0 server. I'd like to build the driver myself so that I can add it to another project as a jar file. I'm struggling to understand the readme on the official repo.

Could someone please explain how to do this, I'm hoping to clone the repo and build in Eclipse. I understand how to clone the repo it's how you go about building the driver.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you have [maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) installed?

Comment: Why not download the jar from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cneo4j-jdbc)?

Comment: Hi @Saheed, yes I do have it installed in eclipse.

Comment: Hi @FrankPavageau, I tried to download the individual components of the driver and add them individually but they didn't work as I expected. I thought this could be because it's not the full driver?

Comment: @MACourtney7, is [this](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/neo4j/driver/neo4j-java-driver/1.0.4/neo4j-java-driver-1.0.4.jar) the version you downloaded? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? I just cloned the project into my Eclipse without any problems.

Comment: @Julian, After cloning the project I want to know how to build the driver so that I may add that jar into another project.

Comment: Doing dependency management manually is tedious and error prone, that's why there are tools for that... Building the project yourself (from the release tag) will give you the same jars you downloaded, it won't really solve anything.

Comment: @MACourtney7, I think you should start with learning to walk before attempting to run. How about you get the [pre-built binary](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver/1.0.4) on Maven working before you attempt to build the driver on your own?

Comment: @MACourtney7 So you want to clone the jar, do some modifications yourself, for instance, and then build it? Well.. you can use Maven for that, search about Maven goals.

Comment: @Saheed, I've added the version 3.0 neo4j-jdbc, neo4j-jdbc-driver, and neo4j-jdbc-bolt as external jars and I am unable to run the example code http://pastebin.com/G6tKxqtf

Comment: @Julian, I don't need to modify anything I just want to be able to connect to a Neo4j server. Within the project I am building tried to convert to a Maven project in eclipse so that I could do this via maven but then my build file no longer functioned.

Comment: @MACourtney7 If you want to connect to a Neo4j server you should create a Maven Project and add the dependencies in your `pom.xml` file and not as a external jar.

Comment: @Julian I converted my current project to a Maven project and then added the suggested jdbc dependency. Now when I try to Maven install it throws and error as it cannot locate the external jars from a different API I am using. Do I need to indicate these local files in the pom.xml too?

Comment: @MACourtney7 No. Maven will automatically download the dependencies to it's own folder and manage it there. There's no need to indicate local files. Try to do `Project -> Clean` on Eclipse, then go to the project and do a `Update Project` by right clicking your project in the Project Explorer. But, do some research on how to properly use Maven, i'm sure it will be good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments it seems that you want to simply connect to a Neo4j server, and as most people recommend you should use Maven or Gradle to work with your dependecies.

For that you're gonna need to create a new Maven Project:

[image: New Maven Project]

and when you finish creating you're gonna have a project similar to this one, the one file you're looking to add this capability to connect to Neo4j is the `pom.xml`:

[image: Project path]

To be able to connect to Neo4j simply add this to the `<dependencies></dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's an example of a `pom.xml` created automaticly by a Spring Starter Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I created a new maven project and copied the sample code from the repo to test if I could get it working at all.

pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/M7EdB5Fx

simple main: http://pastebin.com/fcUaFBpZ

When I attempt maven clean, then maven install I get a build failure.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What error does it give to you? Add -x at the end of your command so you can get a detailed stack trace.

Comment: I've managed to get the neo4j-jdbc-3.0.jar maven dependency useable I am however still no longer able to run the example connection code as some of the objects and methods can not be resolved.

Comment: I guess this does solve the original problem, thanks.